# Find matches in JSON array field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Given a JSON object type column in table `t`, e.g.

```
| id | obj                                | 
| -- | ---------------------------------- |
| 1  | { "params": { "id": [13, 23]} }    |
| 2  | { "params": { "id": [13, 24]} }    |
| 3  | { "params": { "id": [11, 23, 45]} }|
```

and a list of numeric values, e.g. `[12, 23, 45]`.

We need to check every record if it contains values from the given list.
So, the desired result would be

```
| id | matches  |
| -- | -------- |
| 1  | [23]     |
| 3  | [23, 45] |
```

Could someone please help with such a query for the MySQL 8?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_table`:

```
select t2.id, t2.n_obj from (
   select t1.id, (select json_arrayagg(ids.v) 
       from json_table(t1.obj, "$.params.id[*]" columns(v text path '$')) ids 
       where json_contains('[12, 23, 45]', ids.v, '$')) 
   n_obj from t t1) t2 
where t2.n_obj is not null;
```

Comment: As a slight tangent, you might want to look at Multi-Value indexes (see https://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com/2019/08/improved-mysql-query-performance-with.html) as you can index each item in a JSON array for quick lookup.

Comment: Thank you for saving a lot of time and nerves, it works like a charm!

Comment: @DmitryAdonin Glad to help!